# How can I update varbinary(max) columns in SQL Server with flask?

Tags: sql, sql-server, flask, pyodbc, insert-update

I have a `City` table:

```
name | id | pic
-----+----+-----
A    | 1  | null
B    | 2  | null
C    | 3  | null
D    | 4  | null
```

I want to update the `pic` column of this table where `id` is 2. How can I do it?

My code is:

```
file = request.files['file']
saveFileToDB = "UPDATE [Db2].[dbo].[City] SET (pic) VALUES (?) WHERE id = 2"
CU.execute(saveFileToDB, (file.read()))
CU.commit()
```

Error message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)"

or:

```
saveFileToDB = "UPDATE [Db2].[dbo].[City] SET pic = Convert(Varbinary(max),'%s') WHERE id = 2"%file.read()
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `UPDATE City Set pic = ? where id=2` is the SQL syntax.

Comment: I don't think *any* database uses `SET (pic) VALUES (?)`. The standard syntax is `SET field=value`, ie, `SET Pic=?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update syntax is off.  Use this version:

```
file = request.files['file']

saveFileToDB = "UPDATE City SET pic = ? WHERE id = 2"
CU.execute(saveFileToDB, (file.read(),))
CU.commit()
```

As a note, I used `(file.read(),)`, with a trailing comma here.  This is to ensure that Python reads it as a tuple and not a scalar variable.

Comment: not work. i get this error: `pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Warning: Partial insert/update. The insert/update of a text or image column(s) did not succeed. (0) (SQLPutData); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified. (7125)')`

Comment: @Tomy Then it looks like your data itself has another problem.  At least I have corrected your syntax problem.

Comment: i can update image with your code for pic less of 409/kB. for more than 409/kB i get this error pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Warning: Partial insert/update. The insert/update of a text or image column(s) did not succeed. (0) (SQLPutData); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified. (7125)'). but  a VARBINARY(MAX) (the normal 2GB limit ).

Comment: i upload [this](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8385593334/snow_fo_e.jpg) and not work, but when i resize the pic  to less from  70 percent  work [picLess70Percent](http://s7.picofile.com/file/8385593342/snow_fo_e_Copy_2_.jpg).

Comment: thanks from [link](https://github.com/maximemaher/pyodbc/issues/277). i change the  .  con= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=LENOVO-PCN;DATABASE=testing;')      to ===>> con= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=LENOVO-PCN;DATABASE=testing;')    my    means    db = pyodbc.connect ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}.  and update any size file is working.